# Ajax request loads the same posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a question related with Wordpress Ajax posts request. And I can't figure out for hours... Maybe someone will give me advice what I'm doing wrong!

**Problem:**

So I have infinite scroll on my archive pages. Everything is working as it should but for some reason it loads all the time the same 20 posts... What I need to change  to have infinite scroll as long as created posts exists.
Here is my JS code:

```
function loadArticle() {

        var loading = false;

        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {

        var page = $(this).data('page');
        var newPage = page + 1;
        var maxPages = $("#content").data('max-pages');
        var postType = false;
        var search = getQueryVariable("s");



        if ( $('body').hasClass('post-type-archive-news') ) {

            postType = 'news';

        } else if ( $('body').hasClass('post-type-archive-ebooks') ) {

            postType = 'ebooks';

        } else if ( $('body').hasClass('post-type-archive-lookbooks') ) {

            postType = 'lookbooks';

        } else if ( $('body').hasClass('post-type-archive-case-studies') ) {

            postType = 'case-studies';

        } else if ( $('body').hasClass('post-type-archive-events') ) {

            postType = 'events';

        } else if ( $('body').hasClass('search-results') ) {

            postType = false;

        } else {

            postType = 'post';

        }

        var query = 'action=infinite_scroll';

        if ( newPage ) {

            query = query + '&page_no=' + newPage;

        }

        if ( typeof postType == "string" ) {

            query = query + "&post_type=" + postType;

        }

        if ( typeof search == "string" ) {

            query = query + "&search=" + search;

        }

        // Show Loader
        //$('a#inifiniteLoader').show('fast');

        // Load Next Page
        if(!loading && $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('#content').offset().top + $('#content').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight)) {
            loading = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type:'POST',
                data: query,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#content").append(html);    // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
                    loading = false;
                }
            });
        }


        return false;

    });

}
```

And this is my PHP

```
function yieldify_infinite_scroll(){
//init ajax
    $ajax = false;
    //check ajax call or not
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
        strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $ajax = true;
    }
    $paged = $_POST['page_no'] + 1;
    $post_type = $_POST['post_type'];
    $search = $_POST['s'];

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => get_option('posts_per_page'),
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'post_status'       => 'publish'
    );

    if ( $post_type ) {

        $args['post_type'] = $post_type;

    }

    if ( $search ) {

        $args['s'] = $post_type;

    }

    // Load the posts
    //query_posts( $args );

    $ajax_query = new WP_query( $args );

    //echo "<pre>";
    //$print_query = json_encode( $ajax_query, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
    //$print_query = htmlentities( $print_query, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' );

    //print_r( $print_query );
    //echo "</pre>";

    if( $ajax_query->have_posts() ) {

        while( $ajax_query->have_posts() ) { $ajax_query->the_post();

            if ( $post_type ) { ?>
                
                <div class='col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex'>

                    <?php get_template_part('loops/card-new'); ?>
    
                </div><!-- .col -->

            <?php } else {

                echo "<div class='col-12'>";

                    get_template_part('loops/search-results');

                echo "</div>";

            }

        }

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    //check ajax call
    if($ajax) die();
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_infinite_scroll', 'yieldify_infinite_scroll');           // for logged in user
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_infinite_scroll', 'yieldify_infinite_scroll');
```

My archive layout looks like that:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>

        <section id="blog-listing" class="resources-section">

            <div class='container'>

                <div class='row' id="content">

                    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <div class='col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex'>

                            <?php get_template_part('loops/card-new'); ?>

                        </div><!-- .col -->

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div><!-- .row -->
                
                <div class='row'>

                            <div class='col-12 text-center'>

                                <a href="<?php echo get_next_posts_page_link(); ?>" data-current-page="<?php echo $paged; ?>" id="load-more" class="btn btn-blue">Show More</a>

                            </div><!-- .col -->

                        </div><!-- .row -->

            </div><!-- .container -->

        </section><!-- #blog-listing -->

    <?php endif; ?>
```

I would be appreciated for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to update the value in $(this).data('page')

You get it, do an increment on the variable, but you do not store it back. Try to modify as follow.

```
var page = $(this).data('page');
var newPage = page + 1;
$(this).data('page', newPage);
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but it didn't solved the issue...

Comment: did you try to console.log($(this).data('page'))? does it increment? did you try on php side to var_dump($_POST)? are the value correct?

Comment: Hey. I found a solution. I'll share it here today :)